# how to fix Inconsistent or redundant format char 'c' in C?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
char temp[100] = "";
int a, b;

sprintf(temp, "%02c|", "A");

sprintf(tmp, "%02s|", ((b== a) ? ("??") : ("__")));
```

but when I lint it, it says Warning 566: Inconsistent or redundant format char 'c', what is the problem and how to fix it?

And I tried to:
1) changed "A" to 'A' and using "%02c|"
2) change "%02c|" to "%02s|" and keep "A", still the same warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right about inconsistent:

```
sprintf(temp, "%02c|", "A");
```

That should be a character literal `'A'` to match `%c`, not a string literal `"A"`.  If you want to keep the `"A"`, use `%s` instead.

Comment: I changed "A" to 'A' and I also try to use %s and keep the "A", it does not work, the warning is the same!

Answer (score 2):

The `%c` placeholder takes a `char`, not a pointer to a `char`.
Try using `'A'` instead of `"A"`.

Also, it is advisable to always use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: Use `snprintf` if it's available. Pre-C99 implementations may not have it -- and I *think* Microsoft had or had its own `snprintf` function that was incompatible with the C99 standard function of the same name.

Comment: why snprintf beats sprintf?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `"A"` to `'A'`, or change the format to `%s`.